# C# hazelcast client near cache invalidation not working

Tags: c#, hazelcast.net

Have problems with client near cache invalidation not working correctly. We have one client calling remove from a map but then another client calls get and still gets the old version. Using simple remove and get. InvalidateOnChange is set to true on client nearcache config

Seems to work OK with out near cache configured.

Answer (score 0):

The issue appears to be with client near cache invalidation.

The best way to handle this issue is to troubleshoot it. First, make sure the invalidateOnChange is set to true in the near cache configuration. Then, check to make sure the Hazelcast setting on the client side is properly configured. Finally, review the logs to make sure the client is actually seeing the update that the other client is doing. If the issue still persists after these checks, then it is good to open a ticket with Hazelcast support in order to get help from their developers.

Comment: Thanks, client side config all looks good. Are there any logs that show you invalidation of the near cache happening

Comment: Great to hear that the client side config is all good. In regards to your question about logs showing invalidation of the near cache, there should be logs that show the invalidation happening if it is indeed occurring. You can check the logs for messages related to invalidation or cache updates. Additionally, you may want to consider enabling debug-level logging for the cache or Hazelcast to get more detailed information on what's happening in the cache.

Comment: Sorry which logs do you mean, do you mean hazelcast server ones or client. How do I turn on client side logging?